# When being made a room owner automatically or by another room owner, notify me or ask for my confirmation

Tags: feature-request, chat, notifications, room-owner

Stack Exchange should be inclusive.

Owning a chat room implies association with that room. A user might object to such association if it conflicts with how they see themselves. This recently happened to me.

Luckily, one can single-handedly remove one's own room owner status.

Whenever one is made owner of a room, either:

- add a notification to the Inbox ([image: inbox icon]), or
- ask the user if they want to accept this position

Comment: Sounds good, but I don’t see how this is related to inclusivity.

Comment: @SebastianSimon It only affects people who have certain characteristics and would be bothered by being labelled in a way that conflicts with these characteristics.

Comment: While I can understand asking about this for automatic appointments, I would *hope* a manual appointment usually comes with checking in with the appointee first, and as such being unnecessarily redundant there.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell Well, what happened to me was a manual appointment, though not out of malice.

Comment: Well, there's my hopes down the drain then. Well done, cruel world!

Comment: I support this feature request for a different reason. If I visit chat 5 times a year, it is often. Without a notification, I would not even be aware that I became a room owner.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Sure, but does it matter to you that you've become a room owner of some random room? If someone pinged you due to you being a room owner, or something happened (e.g. a chatter got kicked), you'd be notified and find out at that point.

Comment: the word "Stack Exchange" in the first sentence shouldn't be pluralized. The first sentence serves no purpose anyway though other than provoking people.

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica Fixed, thanks. I disagree that it serves to provoke. I, as a member of an often discriminated-against minority group, felt unease with what happened.

Comment: @Adám you don't mention (either in the comments or the question) what happened, so how are we supposed to understand what happened?

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica *"A user might object to such association if it conflicts with how they see themselves. This recently happened to me."* Is it relevant what exact room it was and what part of my identity it conflicted with?

Comment: @EkadhSingh I agree with Adam, we don't need exact details. That's not part of the question and not really relevant to the feature request being asked here.